# How to use `&` and a tag on the same selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

I am trying to write a nested selector that selects a certain tag that has a certain attribute, for example

```
<li foo="bar">
```

To select this, `li[foo="bar"]` would work, but I want to nest it under `[foo="bar"]` using the scss `&` notation because I have other things with the `[foo="bar"]` attribute (e.g., `<div foo="bar" class="baz">`), and I want to group them together. When I try:

```
[foo = "bar"]{
  &li{
    ...
  }
  &.baz{
    ...
  }
}
```

It returns an error that says `li` may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector, and if I try:

```
[foo = "bar"]{
  li&{
    ...
  }
  &.baz{
    ...
  }
}
```

then it says `&` may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: You can try `@at-root li#{&}` - see [the answer to this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41188868/422845).

Comment: @jbyrd this worked, but probably because my selector was indeed for a root (AKA global) selector style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last I heard, this is actually an upcoming feature in SASS 3.3 or 3.4.

See [this thread](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/282) for a question similar to yours and [this thread](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/286) for the proposed solution to be included (which, at the time of writing, seems to be `&__element`).

The issue here isn't the use of `[]` and `&` together - it's the use of a plain element in the selector. Your example with `.baz` should work as expected.

Comment: Right. That was my mistake. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 10):

The right syntax nowadays would be `li#{&}`.

Comment: This will prepend parent selector