# SCSS, simplify/factorize ::after selector

Tags: sass

Let's illustrate with an example.

I want the element `::after` `sort` class to be red, and blue if sort order class is `desc`ending, I use the following scss.

```
.sort {
  ::after{
    color: red;
  }
  &.desc::after {
    color: blue;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify the two `::after` ?

```
.sort::after {
  color: red;
  &.desc {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Is not ok as will be compiled to `.sort::after.desc`.

What I would like to obtain is `.sort.desc::after`.

**Is there a way to simplify my example and remove the duplicated `::after` ?**

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible and probably won't be. See the links to relevant GitHub issues in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511897/how-to-use-and-a-tag-on-the-same-selector)

Comment: @elektronik I would mark your comment as answer to my question if you put is as an answer.

Comment: @ ATX works for me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible and probably won't be. See the links to relevant GitHub issues in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511897/how-to-use-and-a-tag-on-the-same-selector).