# How to use :first-child with tag

Tags: css, sass

This seems like the silliest question, but it has got me stuck. I'm semantically struggling to combine a pseudo selector and tagname with sass

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
.parent {
  &:first-child.. if h4 {
   // styles
  }
}
```

I don't want to target all first childs, just those that happen to be a h4.

If it had a class it would just be `&:first-child.class`

Comment: In LESS, that would be `h4&:first-child`.

Comment: `&:first-child` in your example would match a `.parent` which is the first child of the `.parent`'s parent. You probably don't want that.

Comment: @4castle that is exactly what I do want though.

I'm just trying to do a element type conditional statement.

SLaks above totally just gave me the answer to this!

h4.parent:first-child – this was the output I wanted

Comment: @SLaks Thanks so much, this was the answer I was after. If you convert it I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the tag name before the classname:

```
h4&:first-child
```

Comment: Also, I couldn't find a SASS equivalent without a mixin. Similar issue here – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511897/how-to-use-and-a-tag-on-the-same-selector

Answer (score 0):

Have you try?

```
.parent{
    h4:first-child{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just write

```
.parent {

  h4 {

      &:first-child {
      // styles
      }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this in Sass:

```
.parent {
    h4 {
        // h4 styles...

        &:first-child {

        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't need any styles on the `<h4>` itself, simply:

```
.parent {
    h4:first-child {

    }
}
```

Assuming you are new to Sass, have a look at this article regarding [parent selectors](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand).