# Use trailing ampersand (&) as a class combination selector, not a descendant selector

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass

I want to apply a class `.highlight` to a bunch of different elements and style them according to the element type. I could do this:

```
input[type="text"].highlight {...}
select.highlight {...}
someOtherSelector.hightlight {...}
```

But I'm trying to use the trailing ampersand (&) to make my code more succinct.

I've tried the following:

```
.highlight {

    input[type="text"].& {
        border: 1px solid $brand-purple;
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: property "input" must be followed by a ':'

I've also tried:

```
.highlight {

    input[type="text"]& {
        border: 1px solid $brand-purple;
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Invalid CSS after "[type="text"]": expected "{", was "&"
>   "&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.

Is there a way around this, or can this just not be done in SASS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **`#{&}`** instead of just **`.&`**. And use **`@at-root`** which allows you to break out of your nesting structure entirely to the "root" of your nesting tree.

**Write this in SASS:**

```
.highlight {

  @at-root input[type="text"]#{&} {
      border: 1px solid $brand-purple;
  }
}
```

**This will complied in CSS to:**

```
input[type="text"].highlight {
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will compile to `input[type="text"] .highlight`, not `input[type="text"].highlight` as the OP requested.

Comment: @JonUleis Oh! My bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: Close! But the result of that is `.highlight input[type="text"].highlight {...` instead of just `input[type="text"].highlight {...`

Comment: @jbyrd Updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: That did the trick! Maybe in the end this is more verbose than just repeating highlight, but at least I know it can be done.

Comment: @jbyrd Its my pleasure. Also don't mind accepting this as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorganize your scss a bit, what you need is:

```
input[type="text"]  {
  &.highlight {
    border: 1px solid $brand-purple;
  }
}
```

*Edit after your update, you can use @at-root:

```
.highlight {
  @at-root {
    input[type="text"]  {
      &.highlight {
        border: 1px solid $brand-purple;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know I *can* do that, but I don't want to. I want the `.highlight` class to apply to a bunch of different kinds of elements, without having to repeat `.highlight`

Comment: But that also defeats the whole purpose of my original structuring, because you're having to repeat `.highlight`

Comment: You can use the ampersand that Saurav Rastogi mentioned, but it does basically the same thing - pulls in the parent selector in its place, a bit more elegant solution thou. I don't personalty prefer it because of readability.